# PHP bracket contents to index in array

Tags: php

I want to take the string:

```
(contents) some text (contents two) more text
```

and have it output this array:

```
array(

[contents] => some text
[contents two] => more text

)
```

I've tried looping thru it and using array_push

Comment: please explain in brief.

Comment: I don't know how much briefer I could get

Comment: @bcsb1001 The code is long SO won't let me post with too much code and not enuff text

Comment: Don't post all of your code. Just an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried for this problem, and the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `preg_match_all`(with named submasks `(?<name>)`) and `array_combine` functions:

```
$str = '(contents) some text (contents two) more text';

preg_match_all("/\((?<key>.+?)\) (?<value>[^()]+)/iu", $str, $m, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = array_combine($m['key'], $m['value']);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [contents] => some text 
    [contents two] => more text
)
```

---

**Update:** For your additional request *"make it work if there's no space after the bracket"* with the input string *"(contents)some text (contents two)more text"* : to make it work - change the current regex pattern to as following `"/\((?<key>.+?)\)\s?(?<value>[^()]+)/iu"`

Comment: Can you make it work if there's no space after the bracket

Comment: "(contents)some text (contents two)more text" returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $strInput   = "(contents) some text (contents two) more text";
    $arrChunks  = preg_split("# \(|\) #", $strInput);
    $arrKeys    = array();
    $arrVals    = array();

    foreach($arrChunks as $intKey=>$val){
        if($intKey%2 == 0){
            $arrKeys[] = trim($val, "(");
        }else{
            $arrVals[] = trim($val, ")");
        }
    }

    $arrOutput  = array_combine($arrKeys, $arrVals);
    var_dump($arrOutput);
```

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

According to your example this should work:

```
<?php

$text = "(contents) some text (contents two) more text ";
preg_match( "/\((.+)\)(.+)\((.+)\)(.+)/", $text, $result );
$resultArray [$result [1]] = $result [2];
$resultArray [$result [3]] = $result [4];
print_r($resultArray);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
   [contents] => some text 
   [contents two] => more text
      )
```